# How to show summary data in Laravel Blade inside of ForEach Loop?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade

I am trying to display a ForEach loop on my view that shows each code type.  That part works.  I am having trouble figuring out how to display a count of how many pieces of code (stored in another table) exist for each code type.  I don't understand how to use the id of the code_type to query the code_type_selected table and to return that count.

In my CodeType model

```
protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'color',
    'icon'
];

public function codeTypesSelected() {
    return $this->hasMany(CodeTypesSelected::class, 'code_type_id', 'id');
}
```

In my CodeTypeSelected model

```
 protected $fillable = [
        'code_type_id',
        'code_id',
    ];

    public function codeTypes() {
        return $this->belongsTo(CodeType::class, 'id', 'code_type_id');
    }
```

In my controller

```
public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $codeTypes = CodeType::latest()->get();
        $codeTypesSelected = CodeTypesSelected::latest()->get()->groupBy('code_type_id');
        //dd($codeTypesSelected);
        return view('code_layout.index', compact('codeTypes', 'codeTypesSelected'));
    }
```

And in my view

```
<!-- /. ROW  -->
         <div class="row">
             @foreach($codeTypes as $codeTypeItem)
                 <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                     <div class="panel panel-primary text-center no-boder bg-color-{{ $codeTypeItem->color }}">
                         <div class="panel-left pull-left {{ $codeTypeItem->color }}">
                             <i class="fa fa-{{ $codeTypeItem->icon }} fa-5x"></i>
                         </div>
                         <div class="panel-right">
                             <h3>
                                 {{ count($codeTypesSelected) }}
                             </h3>
                             <strong> {{ $codeTypeItem->name }} </strong>
                         </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
             @endforeach
         </div>
     <!-- /. ROW  -->
```

Comment: `{{ count($codeTypesSelected) }}` this won't work because you are usign `groupBy()` previously, `{{ count($codeTypesSelected[$codeTypeItem->id]) }}`, also laravel collection have a method `->count()`, `{{ $codeTypesSelected[$codeTypeItem->id]->count() }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this

```
CodeType::latest()->withCount('codeTypesSelected')->get()
```

Comment: Thank you, that worked perfectly.  I should have done the count in the controller and not on the view - I had a feeling that wasn't supposed to go there :)  Thanks for the help! :)